# Contact Form 7: Submit button doesn't work in Twitter Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7

I have multiple forms on my site that are loaded in a Bootstrap Modal on a click of a button. For some reason when I try to submit the forms nothing happens. I have checked the browser console and I can't find any errors. Also there is no error in the error_log file.

The code below is what I have for my forms. Have I done something wrong?

**Edit:** I have tested with another form and it seems javascript/jquery is not being loaded in the modal.

```
<button type="button" class="application_button button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#jobapplyform">
    <?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply for job', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?>
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="jobapplyform" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="jobModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">                             
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close-btn-modal" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/close-icon.png"/>
                </button>
                <h2 class="modal-title" id="jobModalLabel">Apply</h2>
            </div>                                   
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="application_details">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="5096" title="Claim This Profile"]'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>                                 
        </div>
    </div>                               
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using bootstrap4.

Please try bellow code

```
    <!-- The Modal -->
 <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#jobapplyform">
    Open modal
  </button>
    <div class="modal" id="jobapplyform">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close-btn-modal" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/close-icon.png"/></button>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal body -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="application_details">
                        <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="5096" title="Claim This Profile"]'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal footer -->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If there is not visibility issue then please try to prevent close when submit button and check if contact form submit button action triggered.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the code didn't work. I also noticed that my file upload input doesn't work either .

Comment: Please check here: https://dev.energypages.com/listing/one-energy click on the request information button

Answer (score 0):

You are missing form element for HTML and type submit for the button, or else the info wont be sent anywhere.